# How to get the latest object using Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: castle-activerecord

I've got a Table of OrderDetails objects and I'd like to get OrderNumber of the latest Order in the database i.e. the Order with the highest OrderDetailsID. 
In SQL I can do the following:

> select Top 1 OrderNumber from orderdetails order by OrderDetailsID desc

How would I go about getting the same thing using ActiveRecord, what Criteria should I be specifying in FindOne(...) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord.AsQueryable<OrderDetails>()
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDetailsID).First().OrderNumber
```

I can't make it any shorter :) you could also do:

```
FindFirst(typeof (OrderDetails), 
    new[] {NHibernate.Criterion.Order.Desc("OrderDetailsID")}, null).OrderNumber;
```